# Mass transfer big files from one Linux box to another Linux box?

Tags: usb, file-transfer

I have tried to transfer about 50 Gb files from a Redhat Linux variant unsuccessfully to my Debian 8.1.

I would like to find other ways than external HDD to move data. There are USB3 connections and HDMI to both machines but nothing else. 
I am not allowed to install BTsync to transfer the files fast between each other.

How can you mass transfer of big files easily between two Linux boxes of different variants?

Comment: Is there a LAN between the machines?

Comment: I need to ask my sysAdmin. I am in the network but cannot find the other.

Comment: Well, there's a lot you can learn. 1. Find out IPs of the two machines. 2. Check if an SSH server is up on one of them. 3. Move the files via SFTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that one machine is running Red Hat and the other Debian won't cause you any problems. For most intents and purposes, the differences between distributions are insignificant.

Realistically, you have two options for your data transfer:

1. Using a removable disk, connected using USB or eSATA or similar.
2. Using the network. Once both machines can connect to one another over the network, you can use any one of a variety of tools to do the file transfer. You mentioned that you cannot using BitTorrent Sync but something like `rsync` may well be an option or, failing, that `sftp` or `scp`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a solid (W)LAN network connection, use a combination of `tar` and *netcat* (`nc`), it will be fast… (**NOTE:** requires netcat on both servers).

On **destination** box:

```
$ nc -l -p 2342 | tar -C /target/dir -xzf -
```

On **source** box:

```
$ tar -cz /source/dir | pv -b | nc Target_Box 2342
```

Comment: Using the option `f -` on tar is like saying "I don't want you to use stdin; please use a file instead. Here you go: stdin."

Answer (score 2):

I use a usb2usb cable (there's basically a networking chip in the middle of the table) to `rsync` my netbook with my laptop. It gets up to about 20-30MBps for bigger files, with `ext4` on both ends. If you want to transfer 50GB quickly, you'll probably be better off with an external HDD. In my experience, the speed then climbs up to 70-100MBps, which more than makes up for the fact that you'll have to transfer the files twice. (Usb2usb cables are handy for small transfers, because you can just plug that in into the usb ports.)

Comment: Can you recommend some cable model, please. I have never realiased some cables work like that. Outstanding idea! I did not find anything by word usb2usb in Finnish biggest reseller of electronics. I need ask such  a cable there.

Comment: I think I have exactly this one: http://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Transfer-Includes-Computer-Software/dp/B005OTPVMY/ref=pd_sim_sbs_328_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=1K8H7EKDKNTVH4SQNRX5

Comment: Does it work with Linux?

Comment: @Masi: If you're thinking of the same store as I am, you're right; they [used to have some](http://www.verkkokauppa.com/fi/product/32451/xmgq), but don't seem to sell them any more. Fortunately, you can [find](http://www.jimms.fi/fi/Product/Show/104816) [them](http://www.kauppasatama.fi/ryhma/USB-linkkikaapeli-kahden-tietokoneen-yhdistamiseksi) in [other](http://www.cruzbroker.fi/deltaco_usb_2_0_linkkikaapeli_kahden_kon_pr_7340004642084.html) [stores](http://www.clasohlson.com/fi/38-4636), or just [use Google](https://www.google.fi/search?q=usb+linkkikaapeli).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, verkkokauppa.com. Do you know if there is any USB3 to USB3 connection -cables? That could increase a lot the transfer speed. I did not find anything in Verkkokauppa.com. Those mentioned ones say that they are designed for PCs but no Linux mentioned. I think PSKocik's cable is only one documented to work with Linux 3.0 kernels.

Comment: I haven't had any problems with it all the way from 3.0 kernels to 3.13 (what I'm on right now). Usually I'd have a 32 bit 3.X kernel on one end and a 64 bit newer kernel on the other.